# How can I filter products in a sales orders line using a value linked to a variant attribute value of a product?

Tags: odoo

I'm using Odoo 8 and I have added the “origen” attribute to the sale_order class, as I mentioned above this field is linked using a many2one relation to a product attribute value.

This is the class definition:

```
class sale_order(osv.osv):
    _name = "sale.order"
    _inherit = 'sale.order'

    _columns = {
        'fecha_entrega_cliente': fields.datetime('Entrega Solicitada'),
        'turno_id': fields.many2one('calendar.event','Turno'), 
        'obra_id': fields.many2one('sale.obra','Obra',          domain="[('name','=',partner_id)]"),
        'ubicacion': fields.char('Ubicacion'),
        'zona': fields.many2one('sale.zona' ,string='Zona'),        
        'origen': fields.many2one('product.attribute.value' ,string='Origen'),
}
```

I want to filter the products shown in a sales order line using the 'origen' attribute. I tried using .xml:

```
<xpath expr="//tree[@string='Sales Order Lines']/field[@name='product_id']" position="attributes">
    <attribute name="domain">[('attribute_line_ids', '=', origen)]</attribute>
</xpath>
```

But it doesn't work…

Also tried this in the .py:

```
class sale_order_line(osv.osv):
    _inherit="sale.order.line"
    _name="sale.order.line"

    _columns={      
        'origen':fields.related('order_id','origen','id',type="integer"
,string="Origen"),
        'product_id': fields.many2one('product.product', 'Product', domain=[('sale_ok', '=', True),('product_variant_ids.attribute_value_ids.attribute_id.id', '=', 'origen')], change_default=True, readonly=True, states={'draft': [('readonly', False)]}, ondelete='restrict'),
```

However, it doesn't show any product.

Comment: Can you more explain what you need? I not understand. `sale.order.line` has no `attribute_line_ids`. `attribute_line_ids` it is field of `product.template`. You can check this: `/addons/product/product.py` line **598**. In order lines use `product.product`, but not `product.template`.